# Filter Search in 2 Android Spinners

Tags: android, search, filter, spinner

I have currently two android spinners, Category and Ratings, which I would like to do a filter search with data from Firebase. Right now I can only search by 1 spinner at a time but I would like the filter search to include 2 spinners.

Below is the code to retrieve the Ratings:

```
 firebase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            shops = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                if (ds.child("ratings").getValue().toString().equals(userSelectRatings)) {
                    shopName = ds.child("shop_name").getValue().toString();
                    phoneNumber = ds.child("phone_no").getValue().toString();
                    categoryOfShop = ds.child("category").getValue().toString();
                    email = ds.child("email").getValue().toString();
                    shops.add(new Shop(shopName, categoryOfShop, phoneNumber, userSelectRatings, email));
                    initializeAdapter();
                }
            }
        }
```

Below is the code to retrieve the Category of shops:

```
firebase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            shops = new ArrayList<>();

            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                if (ds.child("category").getValue().toString().equals(userSelectCategory)) {
                    shopName = ds.child("shop_name").getValue().toString();
                    phoneNumber = ds.child("phone_no").getValue().toString();
                    ratingsOfShop = ds.child("ratings").getValue().toString();
                    email = ds.child("email").getValue().toString();
                    shops.add(new Shop(shopName, userSelectCategory, phoneNumber, ratingsOfShop, email));
                    initializeAdapter();
```

How can I edit my code such that I can filter search by Category AND Ratings instead of just one at a time ? The reason is because both spinners have different listeners so I am not sure how it really works. Your help will be appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Unable to comment, but I'm working under the assumption that you have three sets of data: Categories, Ratings and Data.  The two sections you posted populate the Categories and Ratings, I'm guessing you have another section that populates the Adapter for all the items?

Another assumption is you are populating your Data adapter in the same way, getting all updates so that your DataAdapter is populated.  You should then have a `DataAdapter.Filter` class.

```
Categories.onWhatever -> doFilterData()
Ratings.onWhatever -> doFilterData()

doFilterData()
  Get Category
  Get Rating
  DataAdapater.getFilter().filter(category "~" rating)
```

You filter can then parse the string for category and rating and update the data list as it sees fit.  There isn't much need to go back to the network just to perform filtering, since the data hasn't changed.

The caveats to this are that your DataAdapter has two LIsts, a full list and a filtered list.  You Firebase onDataChange always updates the full list, and your filter class always updates the filtered list.  Your getView, getItem, get* methods should also return from the filtered list.

I've used the same method of filtering in one of my applications and I'm using 4 levels of filtering instead of two.